# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'

Tags: .net-core

When changing pages in my application I am facing a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml': 'Styles'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").

My _Layout section:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved my problem; This is the correct way to do it.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
```